# Can I post questions that I have answered on drupal website (d.o)?

Tags: discussion

Since [answering my own questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is accepted on [DA](https://stackoverflow.com/) and considering that DA has a different audience than [d.o](https://www.drupal.org/), can I post questions that I have answered on d.o ?

I could have done this without asking on Meta, but I think that this is a good way for spreading and maintaining information across both sites and more aspects of a topic may could be enlightened given the majority, the experience and the expertise of those who are involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say yes, with the caveats:

1. The question doesn't already exist, in some form, on DA.
2. You're not blantly just copy/pasting over content in bulk.
3. It's summarizing a long winded thread/page to a more concise question/answer format.
4. It's a topic considered [on topic here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

In short, novel questions brought up / solved on d.o. are ok to post if they're on topic here and been trimmed down to fit the Q&A format.